# R dbGetQuery returning random values instead of NULLs for datetime2 field

Tags: r, odbc

I have just moved using from the RODBC package to odbc/DBI (due to issues with VARCHAR truncating at 255 characters).
dbGetQuery is returning the results of my query - but where a datetime (in fact datetime2) value is NULL, it is returning a random date (sometimes with negative year)
The backend is Azure and the driver is ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.
This is on Windows 10

Any pointers on NULLs not being returned correctly?